# Hide/show an item in bottom navigationbar --Flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to hide/ show an bottomnavigationbaritem depending on a condition ?
Te visibility widget doesn't seem to work .
any suggestions ?

Comment: Show the code for what you have.

Comment: use custom bottom navigation

Comment: Share your attempt to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
var wantShow = true;

void changeState() {
    setState(() {
        wantShow = !wantShow;
    });
}

bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                elevation: 8.0,
                items: [
                  if(wantShow) BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: SvgPicture.asset("${IMAGE_PATH}fi-rr-home.svg"),
                      ),
                      activeIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: SvgPicture.asset("${IMAGE_PATH}fi-sr-home.svg"),
                      ),
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

```
var wantShow = true;

void changeState() {
    setState(() {
        wantShow = !wantShow;
    });
}

bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                elevation: 8.0,
                items: [
                  wantShow ? BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: SvgPicture.asset("${IMAGE_PATH}fi-rr-home.svg"),
                      ),
                      activeIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: SvgPicture.asset("${IMAGE_PATH}fi-sr-home.svg"),
                      ) : SizedBox(),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: That won't work because the `BottomNavigationBar` expects a list of `BottomNavigationBarItem` so you can't add a `SizedBox()` to the item list.